# How does a live test in Google search console affect ranking if it doesn't pick up all the images and other content?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot, google-ranking, live

In google search console I conducted live test URL for my site's home page. However, the screenshot of the live test does not look like my home page.

- There are not many images and text.
- My home page includes a slider.

Will this test result affect Google ranking?

Answer (score 1):

Quite often the live test can have that sort of issues. It has a limited time to test the page and it tried to re-load all resources to make sure it is showing you the latest version.

The real indexing uses caching to store the resources and has longer timeouts so that it can more reliably get everything.

What you do want to be careful about is if Googlebot is being blocked from resources that it would need to show things like your images, text and slider. The URL inspection->View Crawled Page->more info section would indicate if there are any blocking issues.